# Select number of times 2 specific values show up for one record id

Tags: sql-server, join, exists

I'm not sure my title above makes sense, so I'll try to clarify.  I'm using SQL Server.

I have a table called Orders that looks like this (truncated):

```
Order_Number | SKU
           1 | abc
           1 | def
           1 | ghi
           2 | abc
           2 | ghi
           3 | def
           4 | abc
           4 | def
           4 | ghi
           5 | abc
```

I need to find all Order Numbers that include SKUs abc and ghi.  So if I ran the query on the above table, it would return:

```
Order_Number
           1
           2
           4
```

If the Order Number only includes `abc` or `ghi`, not both, I don't want to return the Order Number.  If it includes extra SKUs, such as `def`, that is OK, I still want to return the record.  I don't need to see all the SKUs in the output, just the Order Number.  Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a create table statement and insert statements for sample data that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two different ways:

1) Use [`EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql)

```
SELECT
    Order_Number
FROM
    (-- Get the list of Order_Number
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Order_Number
    FROM
        Orders
    ) AS onr
WHERE
    -- Check that there is an 'abc' associated
    EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM Orders os1
    WHERE os1.Order_Number = onr.Order_Number and os1.SKU = 'abc'
    )
    AND
    -- and also Check that there is an 'ghi' associated
    EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM Orders os2
    WHERE os2.Order_Number = onr.Order_Number and os2.SKU = 'ghi'
  )
ORDER BY
    onr.Order_Number
GO
```

```
| Order_Number |
| -----------: |
|            1 |
|            2 |
|            4 |
```

2) Substitute the `EXISTS` by equivalent `JOINS` with join condition including the desired value of `SKU`:

```
SELECT
    onr.Order_Number
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        Order_Number 
    FROM 
        Orders
    ) AS onr
    JOIN Orders AS sk1 ON sk1.Order_Number = onr.Order_Number AND sk1.SKU = 'abc'
    JOIN Orders AS sk2 ON sk2.Order_Number = onr.Order_Number AND sk2.SKU = 'ghi'
ORDER BY
    onr.Order_Number    
GO
```

You get exactly the same result. Which version you use depends on which one you find clearer to understand. If your tables are really big, test whether one gives a better execution plan.

You can check all the statments at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5f0068f86479849ef8b3ed91b0f59be7)*

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there is a unique constraint on `(Order_Number, SKU)`:

```
SELECT
    sk1.Order_Number
FROM
    dbo.Orders AS sk1
  JOIN 
    dbo.Orders AS sk2 
  ON  sk1.Order_Number = sk2.Order_Number
  AND sk1.SKU = 'abc'
  AND sk2.SKU = 'ghi' ;
```

Tested at **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=854d957a3ad3afc8b7b5bac51466860a)**. Note how with an index on `(SKU, Order_Number)` the execution plan starts with 2 index seeks and doesn't scan the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use window functions which are usually faster,to get OrderNumbers that contain two rows, meaning contain both 'ghi' & 'abc'

```
 ;WITH CTE AS(
 select Order_Number ,SKU
 from Orders
 where SKU ='abc'

 UNION
  select Order_Number ,SKU
 from Orders
 where SKU ='ghi')
 ,
WindowFunction AS(
 select  Order_Number,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Order_Number ORDER BY (select null)) as RowNumber from CTE

 )
 select Order_Number from WindowFunction
where RowNumber = 2
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you might have 3 or more SKUs, and don't want to keep modifying your statement to accommodate the current number:

```
DROP TABLE #OrderItems;
GO
DROP TABLE #SKU_List;
GO

CREATE TABLE #OrderItems (order_id int, SKU varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #OrderItems
VALUES (1,'abc')
      ,(1,'def')
      ,(1,'ghi')
      ,(2,'abc')
      ,(2,'ghi')
      ,(3,'def')
      ,(4,'abc')
      ,(4,'def')
      ,(4,'ghi')
      ,(5,'abc')
;

-- Option 3 - Scalable to more SKUs
--   1. put SKUs in a temp table
--   2. find the number of SKUs that have to be matched
--   3. SELECT order_ids matching any of those SKUs
--   4. GROUP order_ids, COUNT number of DISTINCT SKUs, keep if same as number of SKUS to  match.

CREATE TABLE #SKU_List (SKU varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #SKU_List VALUES ('abc'), ('ghi');

WITH Vars (SKU_Count) AS
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SKU_List)
SELECT oi.order_id
  FROM #OrderItems oi
         INNER JOIN #SKU_List sku ON (oi.SKU = sku.SKU)
         CROSS JOIN Vars
 GROUP BY oi.order_id, Vars.SKU_Count
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT oi.SKU) = Vars.SKU_Count
 ORDER BY order_id
;
```